# Able to click on two items at the same time in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items in a RecyclerView and i set the onClickListener in the onBindViewHolder for each view. The click listener works just fine, the issue is that I can click on two items in the list at the same time and both of them will run their onClick method. When you have ListViews if you try to click on two items at the same time it does not allow you.

For example:
Lets say you are already touching on an item in a listview and during that time you try to touch another item it won't let you. Recyclerview allows that.

How can we make the RecyclerView to work like a ListView for when clicking?

Below is my implementation

```
public class DataCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Data> mDatas = new ArrayList<>();
    private Data mData;

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View card = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
        return  new DataCardViewHolder(mContext, card, mData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Data data = mDatas.get(position);
        ((DataCardViewHolder )holder).configureDataCard(data);
    }

    public static class DataCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private Context mContext;
        private Data mData;

        public DataCardViewHolder(Context context, View view, Data data) {
            super(view);
            mContext = context;
            mData= data;
        }

        public void configureDataCard(final Data data) {
            mData= data;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("DataCardViewHolder","onClick with data: " + mData.getData().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you figuring out that you are clicking at two items at the same time?

Comment: Recyclerview unlike listview does the same behaviour

Comment: @PramodYadav well clicking means touch and then untouch. Maybe i should have said it differently in my description. Basically, lets say you are already touching on an item in a listview and during that time you try to touch another item it won't let you. Recyclerview allows that and this is what i think is causing the issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My RecyclerView is programmatically add in Java but not in xml. And I try this and it works:

```
mRecyclerView.setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(false);
```

If your RecyclerView is add in xml, you may try adding this in your RecyclerView:

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

And now in the recycler-list when you click on one item and don't let go, you can not click another item.

Comment: Hi mate, can you help me to solve this issue please.. I've been stuck many days here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068321/how-do-we-handle-click-from-multiple-item-view-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `RecyclerView` will not handle that for you. Create a `Handler` with timeout:

```
public class DelayedClick {
    protected boolean canClick = true;
    protected Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            canClick = true;
        }
    };

    public boolean getState() {
        if(canClick) {
            myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 200);
            canClick = false;
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!reClick.getState()) {
        return;
    }
    //Code to execute on click
}
```

Comment: `RecyclerView` handles this just fine by invoking `android:splitMotionEvents="false"`

Comment: No, this attribute does not overcome several issues as fast click on one row (and release press), then quickly press another one. Also, if you have two interactive elements in one row, then you can press two things at almost the same time, which can be unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Hi mate, can you help me to solve this issue please.. I've been stuck many days here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068321/how-do-we-handle-click-from-multiple-item-view-in-recyclerview